# Is it possible to change the httpservletrequest object

Tags: java, servlets

Is it possible to change the Servlet request object while forwarding the request from one servlet to another? or a work around for achieving this?

I have 2 servlet's, Servlet1 and Servlet2 like for e.g. -

```
public class Servlet1 extends HttpServlet {
    doPost(HttpServletRequest rq, HttpServletResponse rs) {
       // do something meaningful, call other different web-apps/servlets

       InputStream is1 = rq.getInputStream();
       RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/Servlet2");
       rd.forward(rq, rs);
    }
}
```

If I print the `is1` it is something like -

```
-----Part2_324<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Head><Body><Text>This is the first File</Text></Body></Head>-------Part2_65623
```

I dont care about this o/p, when later the request is to be forwarded to the `Servlet2`.

I have an xml file file2.xml, contents are -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Head><Body><Top>Start</Top><Middle>Process</Middle><Bottom>End</Bottom></Body></Head>
```

I would like this to be as the request content for the `Servlet2`, as it cannot process the contents of `is1`, it is meant to be processing content of file2.xml.
There are pretty much no Attributes/Parameters set.

Is it possible to achieve this? I hope, the question is clear.
Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The servlet spec forbids the substitution of one request for another when forwarding.

However, it *does* permit the forwarding of an `HttpServletRequestWrapper`, where the wrapper is wrapping the original request. So try and implement your logic as a subclass of `HttpServletRequestWrapper`, wrapping the original request, and overriding the various methods of `HttpServletRequest` as appropriate.

Comment: That is it, thats pretty much what I needed. Thanks a lot.